# Unable to package app on x64: Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Release\\project_name.xr.xml

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I need help resolving the following error:

Error   2   Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Release\project_name.xr.xml" because it was not found.

NOTE:
This error does not occur when I package the same solution on x86.
This only occurs on x64.
In addition, this error is now exposed ever since I downloaded VS2012 Update 2.

Comment: VS2012? Or 2013? And try restarting VS.

Comment: There is no VS2013. I restarted VS2012. However, my issue is still not resolved.

Comment: There is a VS2013. I never knew. I'm installing now.

Comment: is your machine 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: My machine is 64 bit.

Comment: @ScottNimrod when you build the solution using x86 config, do you get the file named project_name.xr.xml in obj\x86\Release folder ? if yes did you try pasting the file in obj\x64\Release folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error went away as a result of me fixing the list of warnings that resulted from building the solution.

Comment: Worked for me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was fixed simply by removing spaces from Assembly Name parameter. This can be found in the properties of the Windows 8.1 application project.

[image: Assemble name parameter]

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this is a weird problem and I could not solve it till I looked at the solution from Ken.

[Click here for his solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4d9d8ae7-840d-4e9a-b978-f01c83330a8c/creating-package-fails-for-arm?forum=windowsstore)

Ken's issue and solution gave me an idea and it worked.

I had x:Class="project_name.App" in my App.xaml file and Ken said the issue was with the app name.

So I removed the .App from x:Class="project_name.App" and just had x:Class="project_name" and received the error *"Invalid value for 'project_name'. Event values must be text."*

Ok so I put it back in.

Well, then it worked and the error went away.

Um, I do not have any idea why it now worked as it was exactly the same text, but the process of changing it back and forth fixed it.  Hope this saves someone hours of pain.

And I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 that I reinstalled onto my PC yesterday since the PC had a melt down and needed a rebuild.